# How to tackle existing url's when moving from Joomla to Drupal site

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, joomla

I've a [Joomla site](http://www.creditcardpaymentgateways.in) but I want to move it to Drupal-6 site. How should I go about changing existing url's? Should I add the redirection in .htacces or use any redirect modules?
One main reason of moving is the forum module in Drupal which I'd like to use.
I'd be using nodealias & global redirect modules.
In my site I'm using SH404SEF to generate urls(with .html suffix).

Comment: .htaccess would be ideal, but I don't think it would be realistic to rewrite the URLs to the ones generated by pathauto because there is a lot of replacement going on with PHP when Drupal converts the titles to a path. An alternative may be to write a module that handles the old URLs so you can use PHP to process the requests.

Comment: What type of module are you talking about? What'll be it's function exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely place a redirect in the .htaccess file and reference the pathauto generated path.

http://drupal.org/project/pathauto generates URL aliases based on title etc. and then put something like:

```
RewriteRule ^misc/about.html http://www.example.com/aboutus/ [R=301,L]
```

for each URL. (This is better off in your apache httpd.conf file for performance reasons.)

Or there is a module:

http://drupal.org/project/path_redirect

Which looks like it does just what you want but I've not tried it.